# Same authentication token in multiples symfony application

Tags: symfony, symfony1

When I authenticate in my app1, I get authenticate in my app2 too.

Exemple.

I login at localhost/app1/web/app_dev.pho/login as "foo_user".
When I check my localhost/app2/web/app_dev.php/ I am also authenticated as "foo_user" when I was anon. just before.

Do you know how can I fix that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use in your function something like this

`public function toDo()
    {
        $user = $this->getUser();
         .....
        return ['user' => $user];
    }`

And than in your template use `user` how you want.
It's only one of few examples, how you can do it